# how to lay out a website compatible with mobile and desktop and any browser?

Tags: html, mobile

i recently made a website

http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com

but i messed up big time because it fails at every mobile website tester and its just really
bad
i recently learned about tables
but then i jumped to html5 and learned about flex boxes with web kits
but i see theyre not compatible with all browsers

so im at this endless lopp of trying to find a good not perfect layout that can be viewable from any browser and any size based on what my website has

i tried google with few success and youtube is full of fake webinars

is there any one here who can lead me to finding my answer,, thank you thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) provides a fluid and responsive layout system that can be adapted to work across all devices.

However, in most cases you simply cannot cover all form factors and devices for anything but simple content pages. The idioms you use in a desktop with keyboard and mouse are simple not the same as a touch enabled device.

Find out what your audience will be using, and let that determine your solution. Don't try to be all things to all people.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to retrofit your code, one solution that's always served me well is to use something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), since you can use as much or as little of its functionality as necessary, and it doesn't have much of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something, and want to see how many browsers support that feature you can look at http://caniuse.com/.

You can also look at jQuery Mobile to help, but, you may find more information with this question: [jQuery Mobile for mobile and desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048695/jquery-mobile-for-mobile-and-desktop)

You didn't state what you use for the server-side, but you can easily detect mobile browsers, http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/, 
and change the page you start them on.

I personally like the idea of using REST services for all the data interactions, and then you just have a thin layer of html for UI and formatting, so most of the business logic is centralized.