# JqueryMobile: how to use custom UI elements or modify current UI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop and cross platform app using jqueymobile, it will be on browser and mobile devices. Iam unable to use custom UI elemnts or modify the present UI. 
for example: i want my feilds look like this  [image]

But as of now it shows the feilds with round edges, how can i modify that and this feild are strecthing in browser is there a way i can have control over the size of this UI elements.

Any Data or links on using custom UI with Jquery mobile will be helpful. help is appreciated

Comment: if you want to remove the rounded corners refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463300/how-to-remove-round-corners-in-jquery-mobile http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Comment: refer this one for stretching issue..http://blog.brettalton.com/2012/08/07/limiting-jquery-mobile-page-size/

Comment: @Aravinth thank you...in the blog it is reducing the screen width using media queries but i want to reduce the size of the Textfield or any UI element.

Comment: rounded corners it is ok right..

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048695/jquery-mobile-for-mobile-and-desktop

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @Omar hi..link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Omar what version i should use for best looking mobile and browser application with custom UI

Comment: You can use latest jQM version 1.4.2

Comment: @Omar is there a way i can reduce the side of UI elements, Maybe using Media queries?, i also want to use custom UI elements

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795

Comment: I've updated the answer in that link. If you find it helpful, give it a bump ;)