# Is JqueryMobile layout run on both web and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I make a website in php at backend and HTML,CSS at frontend.Now the requirement is to make it compatible for also mobile.I am thinking to use JqueryMobile but I am confuse that same layout work for both or make different for both.
Is layout make by JqueryMobile cover both ends?Is I make separately JqueryMobile layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery Mobile description:

> jQuery Mobile is a HTML5-based user interface system designed to make responsive web sites and apps that are accessible on all smartphone, tablet and desktop devices.

Then, the same layout will work in both mobile and desktop browsers. Despite that, you should consider how your website looks in desktop browsers if you want to provide different functionalities in each platform.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048695/jquery-mobile-for-mobile-and-desktop?).

jQuery mobile works for both mobile and desktop, but whether or not it looks good on mobile will also depend on your layout in CSS.

Comment: Can you help how to test JqueryMobile? and little bit idea purpose of JqueryMobile, as you say it works for both then what its purpose?

Comment: @haseeb The purpose of jQuery mobile is to replicate the native look & feel of mobile applications. It can do a bunch, but major features are making your site responsive to touch, and using a grid system that automatically rearranges based on the size of the viewer window.